# Как использовать js-переменную внутри jQuery.validate?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На форме обратной связи у меня есть поле `<input id="name_user" name="name_user" value="">`.
Это поле обязательно к заполнению. Решил добавить клиентскую валидацию при помощи jquery.validate.js

```
//Инициализирую js переменную, в которой будет храниться имя моего input поля.
var name="name_user"

//Запускаю валидацию полей при отправки формы
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
                required: true
            }
    },

    messages: {
         name: {
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения"
         }
    },
});
```

Внутри `$("#form").validate({ ... })` переменная name не видна.

Как я могу переменную "name" использовать в том месте?

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том, что внутри `rules(messages)`  функция ждёт не переменную, а атрибут `name` от любого `input` формы, поэтому, исходя из вашего кода, функция пытается найти `input[name='name']` и не находит его. Ну и это значит, что передать переменную `name` в функцию нельзя. Поэтому надо использовать так в вашем случае:

```
'rules: {
        name_user: {
                required: true
            }
    }'
```

**UPD**

Попробуйте сделать так, если у вас динамический `name` у `input`:

```
var name = $('input[name="'+ name_user +'"]');
```

Comment: У меня имя элемента динамическое. Т.е. имя всегда разное, например: property_123

Comment: @МаринаВоин, обновил ответ

Comment: Получить name динамического инпута я могу. А вот как присвоить этому инапуту валидацию - не знаю. Так как внутри `$("#form").validate({ ... })` переменная не видна.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать `.rules()`

[Доки](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то:

```
var name="name_user"; //объявляется вне функций -> глобально
```

то тогда ваша переменная будет доступна везде через:

```
window.name;
```

**но "стандартные" имена (name) лучше не использовать, можете нечаянно заменить уже существующее свойство у объекта window!**

Answer (score 0):

```
var name="name_user";

var rules = {},
    messages = {};

rules[name] = {required: true};
messages[name] = {required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения"}

$("#form").validate({
    rules: rules,

    messages: messages,
});
```

Так совсем не подходит? Конечно, она не видна, это же объект.